# VB6 week of day function

Tags: vb6, dayofweek

I'm relatively new to VB6 and I've just been given an assignment where I have a date - for example '4/12/2016' - from this date, i'm trying to find out the day that it is. So let's say it's a wednesday. Now from this day, I'm trying to determine the dates for the week [sun(startdate) - sat(enddate)). How would I go about doing something like this?

EDIT: I have a pretty good idea about finding out the date for sunday and saturday, since I can simply do something along the lines...

```
dim dateStart,dateend as date

Ex of date given to me = '4/12/2016'

Dim dateDay as variant
dateDay = whatever I get here - i'm assuming that a date will return a number for whatever day it is ???? Not sure
Select Case dateDay
case 1 -Monday?
      dateStart=dateadd("d",-1,'4/12/2016) 
      dateEnd = dateadd("d",6, '4/12/2016) 
case 2 -Tuesday?
      datestart = dateadd("d",-2,'4/12/2016)
      dateend = dateadd("d",5,'4/12/2016)

End Select
```

Basically do the SELECT statement for all cases. Am I on the right track?

Comment: See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx. Please do research before asking questions - I got that as the first result from searching for vb6 dayofweek (i.e. exactly your tags), along with http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic

Comment: VB6 URL for the Weekday function, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263404(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet The Weekday function isn't available in VB6. See my answer below.  Unfortunately, Microsoft do their best to reroute all VB6 searches to VB.Net documentation.

Comment: @BobRodes: Fair enough - apologies to all.

Comment: @JonSkeet No apology necessary for me. We diehard VB6 coders run into this all the time, and I will also say that I've spent a fair amount of time poring over your C# posts to advantage.  :)

Comment: @BobRodes: _The Weekday function isn't available in VB6_.  Uh, what?  Sure it is. Jac provided the vb6 documentation url in the above comment.  VB6 (as does vb.net) also provides the WeekdayName function that'll return the day of the week in text, no need for the case code in your answer (if days-as-text is what you're after, of course).

Comment: @MarkL Well, now I'm embarrassed.  I looked for it, too.  Even tried it and got an error, must have done the syntax wrong.  I've always done it the way I published.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @BobRodes, No problem, I understand.  Actually, the exciting part of this is I'm able to confirm that JonSkeet got something right!  :)

Comment: @bobrhodes it is available - i used the weekday function. dim x as integer....... x = weekday(4/15/2016). X = 6. Then I do select case 1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7 and i do DATEadd - everything works like a charm.

Comment: @MarkL And here I was thinking he had actually gotten something wrong.  Should have known better.  LOL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code:

```
Debug.Print Format(DatePart("w", Now), "dddd")
```

will print whatever day of the week it is now to the Immediate window.  If you want the abbreviated day of week, use "ddd" for the format.

Now, this code:

```
Dim DOW As String
Select Case DatePart("w", Now)
    Case vbSunday
        DOW = "Sunday"
    Case vbMonday
        DOW = "Monday"
    Case vbTuesday
        DOW = "Tuesday"
    Case vbWednesday
        DOW = "Wednesday"
    Case vbThursday
        DOW = "Thursday"
    Case vbFriday
        DOW = "Friday"
    Case vbSaturday
        DOW = "Saturday"
End Select
Debug.Print DOW
```

will do the same thing.  However, it shows you how to evaluate programmatically which day of the week you're dealing with, by using vbSunday, vbMonday, etc.  That should give you what you need to get started on your Select statement.  To use your example, `DatePart("w", "4/12/2016")` evaluates to 3, or vbTuesday.

VB6 reference documentation is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338032(v=vs.60).aspx), and rather well hidden I might add.  Look up Format and DatePart to get familiar with other options.

EDIT: As MarkL points out, the Weekday function is available in VB6 (I thought it wasn't), and is simpler (one less argument) than using DatePart.  This code:

```
Debug.Print Format(Weekday(Now), "dddd")
```

will also print whatever day of the week it is to the immediate window.  jac has also provided a link to the Weekday function in the comments above.

Comment: Yah i acctually forgot about this post, so when I read your comment i wasn't sure what you were talking about because it was working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try below codes, The code will return name of the day.

```
txtDateTime.Text = WeekdayName(Weekday(Now))
txtDateTime.Text = WeekdayName(Weekday(12 / 30 / 1995))
txtDateTime.Text = WeekdayName(Weekday(Date))
```